# OnsenUIで画面遷移のボタンを複数押すと、押した分画面が出てきてしまう件

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

```
<ons-button modifier="quiet" ng-click="Navigator.pushPage('hoge.html', { animation : 'lift' } )">hoge</ons-button>
```

というボタンを設置して、
そのボタンを複数回押すと、押した数だけ画面が出てきてしまいます。

それを防ぐような処理はどうしたら良いでしょうか？

教えていただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ボタン押下後は画面遷移処理を無効にしておき、遷移終了したタイミングで再び遷移処理実行可能にすればよいです。[`navigation.pushPage()`](http://onsen.io/guide/components.html#ons-navigator) の `options` では、`onTransitionEnd` にコールバック関数が指定できます。

以下のようになります。

*root page*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        ...
        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.isPushing = false;
            $scope.pushTo = function( pageName) {
              if ($scope.isPushing) return;
              $scope.isPushing = true;
              $scope.myNavigator.pushPage(pageName, {
                animation : 'lift',
                onTransitionEnd: function() { 
                  $scope.isPushing = false;
                }
              });
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
...
```

*ons page*:

```html
    <ons-button modifier="quiet" ng-click="pushTo('page2.html')">
        hoge
    </ons-button>
```

Comment: 早速ご回答ありがとうございます！！
こちらは、すべてのviewに設置したボタンに同様の記述をするとなると、なかなか煩雑になってしまうのが気になるのですが、それは仕方ないものでしょうか？

Comment: `<button>`要素に付ける記述は、`ng-click="pushTo('XXXX.html')` だけです。画面遷移が同時に起こることはないので、 `isPushing` は共通で使えますし、`pushTo()` 関数は、アプリケーションで一つあれば良く、全ページで使い回せます。関数の宣言は１つで良いです。 /// もし AngularJS の機能を生かしてスマートに作るとすれば、新しいディレクティブを宣言することになるのかと思いますが、基本的な仕組みは「`onTransactionEnd` が起こるまでボタンによる動作を無効にする」ということで、同じになる上、タグに付加するコードも大差ないと思いますよ。（まあ、Monaca に慣れていないので、もしかすると、もっといい方法があるのかもしれませんが・・・）